# Neo4j logging in to 2.2.5

Tags: logging, neo4j

After upgrade to Neo4j 2.2.5 i see in */graph.db/messages.log queries from cypher :

```
2015-09-30 10:42:31.319+0000 DEBUG [o.n.k.i.q.QueryExecutionEngine]: 
MATCH (n:Identity) 
WHERE ((NOT has(n.lifecycleState)) OR n.lifecycleState <> 'DELETED') 
AND n.login = {login} 
RETURN n
```

How can i disable this messages?

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak logging verbosity in `conf` very easily. As an example the following two files prevent logging of each an every statement in 2.2.5. Just change `conf/custom-logback.xml` to:

```
  <logger name="org.neo4j.cluster.protocol" level="warn">
  </logger>

  <logger name="org.neo4j.cluster.NetworkMock" level="warn">
  </logger>

  <logger name="org.neo4j.kernel.ha" level="warn">
  </logger>

  <logger name="org.neo4j.cluster.protocol.heartbeat" level="info">
  </logger>

  <logger name="org.neo4j.kernel.info.DiagnosticsManager" level="info">
  </logger>

  <conversionRule conversionWord="module"
                  converterClass="org.neo4j.kernel.logging.ModuleConverter" />

  <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <filter class="org.neo4j.kernel.logging.ConsoleLoggingFilter" />
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ,UTC} %-5level [%module] %message%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <logger name="org.neo4j" level="warn">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
  </logger>

</included>
```

And `conf/logging.properties` to:

```
    # Properties file which configures the operation of the JDK
    # logging facility.

    # The system will look for this config file, first using
    # a System property specified at startup:
    #
    # >java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=myLoggingConfigFilePath
    #
    # If this property is not specified, then the config file is
    # retrieved from its default location at:
    # JDK_HOME/jre/lib/logging.properties

    # Global logging properties.
    # ------------------------------------------
    # The set of handlers to be loaded upon startup.
    # Comma-separated list of class names.
    # (? LogManager docs say no comma here, but JDK example has comma.)
    handlers=java.util.logging.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

    # Default global logging level.
    # Loggers and Handlers may override this level
    # SEVERE, INFO, FINE, FINEST
    .level=WARN

    # Loggers
    # ------------------------------------------
    # Loggers are usually attached to packages.
    # Here, the level for each package is specified.
    # The global level is used by default, so levels specified here simply act as
    # an override.
    org.neo4j.server.level=WARN

    # Handlers
    # -----------------------------------------

    # --- ConsoleHandler ---
    # Override of global logging level
    java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=WARN
    java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=org.neo4j.server.logging.SimpleConsoleFormatter
    java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.filter=org.neo4j.server.logging.NeoLogFilter

    # --- FileHandler ---
    # Override of global logging level
    java.util.logging.FileHandler.level=ALL

    # Naming style for the output file (the output file is placed in the directory
    # defined by the "user.home" System property):
    #     "/" the local pathname separator
    #    "%t" the system temporary directory
    #    "%h" the value of the "user.home" system property
    #    "%g" the generation number to distinguish rotated logs
    #    "%u" a unique number to resolve conflicts
    #    "%%" translates to a single percent sign "%"
    java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern=data/log/neo4j.%u.%g.log

    # Specifies whether the FileHandler should append onto any existing files
    # (defaults to false):
    java.util.logging.FileHandler.append=true

    # Limiting size of output file in bytes (10M):
    java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit=10000000

    # Number of output files to cycle through, by appending an integer to the base
    # file name:
    java.util.logging.FileHandler.count=10

    # The name of the character set encoding to use (defaults to the default
    # platform encoding):
    #java.util.logging.FileHandler.encoding=

    # Style of output (Simple or XML):
    java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

Comment: Yes you are right ... to disable this log is to set in conf/custom-logback.xml from <logger name="org.neo4j" level="all"> to <logger name="org.neo4j">